# C# compilation error converting char[] into string[]

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to compile a c3 program but I keep on getting the error below.

> Error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `string.Join(string, string[])` has some invalid arguments.
>
> Error CS1503: Argument `#2` cannot convert `char[]` expression to type `string[]`

```
for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
{
    char[] arr = new char[3];
    for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
    {
        if (board[row, col] == Player.None)
        {
            arr[col] = ' ';
        }
        else
        {
            arr[col] = board[row, col] == Player.P1 ? 'X' : 'O';
        }
    }
     
    Console.WriteLine("| {0} |", string.Join(" | ", arr));
```

Comment: Well everything is in the message : you're creating a char array while your method is expecting a string array...

Comment: Duplicate of [How to convert a char array to a string array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7936235/).

Answer (score 3):

The answer is very simple, `arr` is a `char[]` and not a `string[]`.

try this

```
Console.WriteLine("| {0} |", string.Join(" | ", arr.Select(a => a.ToString())));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could either iterate the `char`s ([as suggested by others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19974666/112407)) of the array or you could change the type of the array

```
for (int row = 0; row < 3; row++)
{
    var arr = new string[3];
    for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++)
    {
        if (board[row, col] == Player.None)
        {
            arr[col] = " ";
        }
        else
        {
            arr[col] = board[row, col] == Player.P1 ? "X" : "O";
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("| {0} |", string.Join(" | ", arr));
}
```

Comment: This is actually probably the best solution - using the right array type in the first place. Well done on looking at the problem fully rather than just fixing the erroring line (which is what I did in my head before others answered what I intended to).

Answer (score 0):

As your `arr` is of type `char[]`, you can use [String(char[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttyxaek9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) constructor to create `string` object instance

```
var strData= new string[]{new string(arr)};
Console.WriteLine("| {0} |", (string.Join(" | ", strData));
```

Comment: This will return `| Foo |` when the input is `{'F', 'o', 'o'}`, I suspect OP wants `| F | o | o |` in that case.

Comment: @RuneFS: Despite me upvoting your comment I just checked and it will accept a string fine. ALthough I've not looked at the docs this second I think it has a params string[] overload (or similar) that means a single string is fine (if a little pointless).